Reverse lookup is failing in docker
I have the following simple gocode
func FullyQualifiedHostname() (string, error) {
    // 1. Get the machine hostname. Example: localhost
    hostname, err := os.Hostname()
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("FullyQualifiedHostname: failed to retrieve the hostname of this machine: %v", err)
    }

    // 2. Look up the IP address for that hostname. Example: 127.0.0.1
    ips, err := net.LookupHost(hostname)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("FullyQualifiedHostname: failed to lookup the IP of this machine's hostname (%v): %v", hostname, err)
    }

    if len(ips) == 0 {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("FullyQualifiedHostname: lookup of the IP of this machine's hostname (%v) did not return any IP address", hostname)
    }

    // If multiple IPs are returned, we only look at the first one.
    localIP := ips[0]

    // 3. Reverse lookup the IP. Example: localhost.localdomain
    resolvedHostnames, err := net.LookupAddr(localIP)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("FullyQualifiedHostname: failed to reverse lookup this machine's local IP (%v): %v", localIP, err)
    }

    if len(resolvedHostnames) == 0 {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("FullyQualifiedHostname: reverse lookup of this machine's local IP (%v) did not return any hostnames", localIP)
    }
    
    return strings.TrimSuffix(resolvedHostnames[0], "."), nil

    }


i am trying to run this inside a docker container (this is part of a larger program) but I am getting the following error
FullyQualifiedHostname: failed to reverse lookup this machine's local IP (192.168.65.3): lookup 3.65.168.192.in-addr.arpa. on 192.168.65.7:53: no such host

I tried adding dns while running the docker container but that did not help.
Can anyone help in this ?

What OS's are in use? (Host and container). This issue may be relevant.

How are you running the container?  What do you hope to do with this name once you find it?

@Brits the host machine is macos and the docker's base image is Ubuntu 20.04

@DavidMaze it was used by a different part of the code. Some MySQL reverse proxy thing that I am not very sure of.

Have you verified that there is a reverse pointer DNS set for that IP? This is not something that happens "magically", you have to configure your DNS to expose a PTR record. https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-ptr-record/

This is what I get when I do dig -x 
myuser@docker-desktop:~$ dig -x 192.168.65.3

; <<>> DiG 9.16.48-Ubuntu <<>> -x 192.168.65.3
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 20329
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;3.65.168.192.in-addr.arpa. IN PTR

;; Query time: 48 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.65.7#53(192.168.65.7)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 11 22:11:47 IST 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 43```
